# How to determinate file in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I use File::Find -> find(\&f, $directory) for find some file with some content.
Relevant part of my delegate looks like:

```
sub f {
  my $file = $File::Find::name;
  return unless -f $file;
  return unless $file =~ /$file_pattern/;

  etc...
```

but the problem is that, that this code returns every time where $file not exist in current directory.
For example for file ./test it fine, but for file ./dir/test this return...

Is there some better way to know if $file is file?

Comment: Works fine for me. I think your problem is some other statement. If you can get proper results from `-f '/full/path/to/file'` then `$File::Find::name` is the same thing and it shouldn't matter what directory you or the file is in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for replays, but you are wrong :)
Here is some bug. It work only with full path.
I perform some test. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

print "++ With relative path ++\n";
find(\&f, ".");

print "\n++ With current working directory module ++\n";
find(\&f, cwd);

sub f
{
        my $file = $File::Find::name;
        print $file . ":\n";

        if (-f $file) { print "---- ist Datai\n"; }
        else { print "---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!\n"; }
}
```

Here are the commands:

[andrey@andreys-comp testdir]$ ls -l innerdir/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 andrey andrey 0 Jun 18 22:02 innertestfile
[andrey@andreys-comp testdir]$ ./test.pl
++ With relative path ++
.:
---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!
./test.pl:
---- ist Datai
./testfile:
---- ist Datai
./innerdir:
---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!
./innerdir/innertestfile:
---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!

++ With current working directory module ++
/home/andrey/testdir:
---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!
/home/andrey/testdir/test.pl:
---- ist Datai
/home/andrey/testdir/testfile:
---- ist Datai
/home/andrey/testdir/innerdir:
---- ist nicht eine Datei!!!
/home/andrey/testdir/innerdir/innertestfile:
---- ist Datai

ist Datei: is file
ist nicht eine Datei: is not file (I just like German :) )

Put your attension that in first method ./innerdir/innertestfile not determined as file, rather than in second.

Comment: Who and why downscore my answer?

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
return unless -f $file;
```

will return if $file is not a file (it could be a folder)

This line

```
return unless $file =~ /$file_pattern/;
```

will return if the file **name** does not contain $file_pattern.

Note that this sub f() does NOT tell File::Find which files to find, according to the documentation...

> The wanted() function does whatever
>   verifications you want on each file
>   and directory. Note that despite its
>   name, the wanted()  function is a
>   generic callback function, and does
>   not tell File::Find if a file is
>   "wanted" or not. In fact, its return
>   value is ignored.

To find all files in a folder you may find it easier to use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule).  Here is an example from the docs...

```
  my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                              ->name( '*.pm' )
                              ->in( @INC );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, but you are not exactly understood my question. I found my problem, see my last post.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking with

```
if (! -f $file) { 
   die "not a file";
}
```

Comment: I would think you want to *ignore* directories, not die if `File::Find::find` *inevitably* includes them.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, but you are not exactly understood my question. I found my problem, see my last post.